# Try to build a fillable pdf form with pdf-lib via user input (Nextjs, Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a website where user can put their input with html form and generate the value of user that has enter and display the pdf file with the values of the user input. I'm using NextJs. For pdf reader library I'm using PDF-Lib [here the documentation of pdf-lib] https://pdf-lib.js.org/ and I using React useContext to manage state of user input and store it in the cookie with js-cookies. There no issue with user input and storing value.

Example form picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/phbtT.png

And here the code of the picture above. There no issue in here yet

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { Store } from '../utils/Store';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function BorangScreen() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
  } = useForm();

  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { pks } = state;
  const { borangPks } = pks;
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue('totalgrant', borangPks.totalgrant);
  }, [setValue, borangPks]);

  const submitHandler = ({ totalgrant }) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SAVE_FORM_PKS',
      payload: { totalgrant },
    });
    Cookies.set(
      'pks',
      JSON.stringify({
        ...pks,
        borangPks: {
          totalgrant,
        },
      })
    );
    router.push('/pdf');
  };

  return (
    <Layout title="Borang Pks">
      <div>
        <form
          className="mx-auto max-w-screen-md"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}
        >
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="totalgrant">
              Total Grant Amount / Jumlah Geran keseluruhan
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              maxlength="10"
              className="w-full"
              id="totalgrant"
              autoFocus
              {...register('totalgrant', {
                required: 'Please enter amount',
                maxLength: 10,
              })}
            />
            {errors.totalgrant && (
              <div className="text-red-500">{errors.totalgrant.message}</div>
            )}
            {errors.totalgrant && errors.totalgrant.type === 'maxLength' && (
              <div className="text-red-500">Limit to 10 digit </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4 flex justify-between">
            <button className="primary-button">Next</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

BorangScreen.auth = true;
```

Then when user click next button and will redirect user to the /pdf pages where it will show the pdf file that have generate with user input values. Here the picture of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJBF.png

And here the code inside the pages

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { Store } from '../utils/Store';
const { writeFileSync, readFileSync } = require('fs');

export default function Pdf() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { pks } = state;

  const createPdf = async(input, output) => {
    try {
      // async load pdf document
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFileSync(input));

      // Modify document, fill out the form...
      const fieldNames = pdfDoc
        .getForm()
        .getFields()
        .map((f) => f.getName());
      console.log({ fieldNames });

      const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

      // fill form text document
      form.getTextField('totalgrant').setText(pks.borangPks.totalgrant);

      form.flatten();

      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      await writeFileSync(output, pdfBytes);
      console.log('PDF created!');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  // exec pdf output
  createPdf('./public/1.pdf', './public/Borang Geran PKS.pdf'); // (input, output)

  return (
    <Layout title="Borang PKS">
      <div>
        <iframe
          id="pdf"
          type="application/pdf"
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}
          src="Borang Geran PKS.pdf"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

So the question/issues is when I'm define the values in here code below and console.log(borangPks.totalgrant)  the values is undefined in the terminal but in the chrome devtools it showed the value of the totalgrant: '10000' <-- let say the user enter 10000 for totalgrant form.

```js
export default function Pdf() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { pks } = state;
  const { borangPks} = pks;
  console.log(borangPks.totalgrant)
```

And when I'm define the values in here ofcos it will show undefined

```js
 form.getTextField('totalgrant').setText(borangPks.totalgrant);
```

I have try String() function and still undefined

```js
 form.getTextField('totalgrant').setText(String(borangPks.totalgrant));
```

but when I call the values inside the any html tag it show the value

```js
return (
    <Layout title="Borang PKS">
      <div>
        <p>{pks.borangPks.totalgrant}</p>
        <iframe
          id="pdf"
          type="application/pdf"
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}
          src="Borang Geran PKS.pdf"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
```

Here the example picture above issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf5zJ.png

I know I'm do something wrong in the async function and what is it?

can someone help this issue. Thank You